# JPA: Persisting a Map<String,Entity>

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Could you help to persist a Map when String is not the key of the Entity mapped?
For example:

```
class A {

   @Id
   long id;

   String code;
}

class B {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @What magical combination of JPA annotations should I use here?! 
   Map<String,A> mapAByCode;

}
```

I've tried a lot of combinations of {@JoinTable,@MapKeyColumn,@JoinColumn,@JoinTable} annotations with no success and I'm going crazy...

Thanks!

Comment: Why did MapKeyColumn not work?  Check out http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/MapKeyColumns for help

Comment: @MapKeyColumn(name = "CODE") creates a field (named "CODE") that maps id primary key. @MapKeyColumn(name = "A_CODE") doesn't work either

Comment: MapKeyColumn defines the field used in the relation table to store the key value.  It is used for extra information.  All you seem to want is to hash your entities in the map based on the A.code value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want to map your entities using the A.code value, @MapKey is what you are after.  @MapKey allows you to define the value within the reference to use as the key for the map.  As the javadoc states, it is required to be unique though or you will run into problems.

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @MapKey(name="code")
  Map<String,A> mapAByCode;
```

Comment: I don't know what's going on. Using @MapKey(name="code") map data are wrong deserialized: map keys I obtain are A ids instead of A codes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is related to other map I'm using in the same class:

```
@Entity
class A {

  @Id
  long id;

  String code;
}

@Entity
class B {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "B_MAPABYID", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
    @MapKey(name="id")
    Map<Long,A> mapAById;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "B_MAPABYCODE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
    @MapKey(name="code")
    Map<String,A> mapAByCode;

}
```

This configuration is not working for me, but if I set mapAById as transient all works fine. Does it makes any sense for you?

Comment: Since I couldn't workaround the problem I decided to change the Map to Map<String,Long> mapAidByCode and take the A instances in to steps mapAById.get(mapAidByCode.get("code1")). I just define this map of basic types with the simple @ElementCollection annotation.